# How to get pagination links in resource collection - Laravel 5.7.19

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working with laravel API resource. when we don't use any resource collection we get pagination links etc with paginate(10). but when i use Resource::collection i get nothing, just the fields i put in resource.

**This is my Controller**

```php
return response()->json([
  "items" => LatestProjectsResource::collection(Project::has('pages')->where('type', $type)->latest()->paginate(20))
]);
```

**And this is my Resource**

```php
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->name,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'url' => $this->url,
            'thumbnail' => new ThumbnailResource($this->thumbnail),
        ];
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

I tried some answers from online community including this [Customising Laravel 5.5 Api Resource Collection pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094741/customising-laravel-5-5-api-resource-collection-pagination) one but its not working

I tried `$this->collection` but no luck

Please help me out here.

Comment: Have you tried returning `['data' => $this->collection]` from your resource?

Comment: Yes! its gives me null

Comment: The links are missing because of your custom response. It works with `return LatestProjectsResource::collection(...);`, but then the main key is named `data` instead of `items`. Does it have to be named `items` in your case?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue by overriding a regular resource class's `collection` method.

```
public static function collection($data)
{
    /* is_a() makes sure that you don't just match AbstractPaginator
     * instances but also match anything that extends that class.
     */
    if (is_a($data, \Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator::class)) {
        $data->setCollection(
            $data->getCollection()->map(function ($listing) {
                return new static($listing);
            })
        );

        return $data;
    }

    return parent::collection($data);
}
```

This simply checks if the given data is and instance of Laravel's paginator classes and if it is, it just modifies the underlying collection and returns the same paginator instance. You can put this in an abstract collection class or in every resource class.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code clean make a PaginationResource to be used across different collections and make single place for editing pagination details

then inside any resource add your Pagination resource as follow

#### this is Pagination resource

```php
public function toArray($request) : Array
    {
        return [
            'total' => $this->total(),
            'count' => $this->count(),
            'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'total_pages' => $this->lastPage()
        ];
    }
```

and add it to any other collection like this

```php
 public function toArray($request) : Array
    {
        $pagination = new PaginationResource($this);

        return [
            'templates' => $this->collection,
            $pagination::$wrap => $pagination,
        ];
    }
```