# How to remove links in the meta object of Laravel paginate response?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, lumen, laravel-resource

Laravel default paginate gave me the response with default format for pagination, but I want to remove links in the meta object at the page response

I used below code to fetch the page data:

```
public function index()
{
  return response()->json(
     new EntityCollection(Entity::paginate($pageSize))
  );
}
```

It return the response in resource collection I called EntityCollection in my codes. But I want to remove links in the meta at the response.

EntityCollection looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class EntityCollection extends ResourceCollection
 {

 /**
  * Transform the resource collection into an array.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return array
  */
  public function toArray($request)
  {
     return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
     ];

  }
}
```

When I use EntityCollection to fetch the list it returns below format response:

```
{
"data": [
    // data
],
"links": {
    "first": "*url?page_size=1&page=1",
    "last": "*url?page_size=1&page=15",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "*url?page_size=1&page=2"
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 15,
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "pagination.previous",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "*url?page_size=1&page=6",
            "label": 6,
            "active": false
        }
   ],
    "path": "*url",
    "per_page": "1",
    "to": 1,
    "total": 15
 }
}
```

Please give me the way to remove links in the meta or the best practice to customise the response of paginate in Laravel.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094741/customising-laravel-5-5-api-resource-collection-pagination/50032477#50032477

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Core\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection;

class AppAnonymousResourceCollection extends AnonymousResourceCollection
{
    public function paginationInformation($request, $paginated, $default): array
    {
        return [
            'pagination' => [
                'currentPage' => $paginated['current_page'],
                'from' => $paginated['from'],
                'lastPage' => $paginated['last_page'],
                'perPage' => $paginated['per_page'],
                'to' => $paginated['to'],
                'total' => $paginated['total'],
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Core\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AppJsonResource extends JsonResource
{
    public static function collection($resource)
    {
        return tap(new AppAnonymousResourceCollection($resource, static::class), function ($collection) {
            if (property_exists(static::class, 'preserveKeys')) {
                $collection->preserveKeys = (new static([]))->preserveKeys === true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```php
class AcmeResource extends AppJsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  Request| null  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request = null): array
    {
        return [
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

On controller..

```
return AcmeResource::collection($collection->paginate($limit))
            ->response();
```

Result:

```json
{
    "data": [
        ...
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "currentPage": 2,
        "from": 4,
        "lastPage": 7,
        "perPage": 3,
        "to": 6,
        "total": 21
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Good solution for me

Comment: In `AppJsonResource` you can just redeclare `newCollection` method

Answer (score 1):

It is simple by creating this method from your own collection, EntityCollection:

```
public function paginationInformation($request, $paginated, $default)
{
    unset($default['links']);
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: it also works for `meta` key

Answer (score 1):

This was always a PIA for me.

The suggestions / answers you will find will involve the creation of multiple collections, probable undefined keys if you use the wrong `paginate` method, etc.

What I like to do is simple, I add one more function to an Eloquent Builder, so you can just do `jsonPaginate()`.

`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

public function boot()
{
    Builder::macro('jsonPaginate', function (int $perPage = 15) {
        /** @var Collection $this */
        $json = $this->paginate($perPage)->toArray();
        $json['meta'] = [
            'from'      => $json['from'],
            'to'        => $json['to'],
            'last_page' => $json['last_page'],
            'per_page'  => $json['per_page'],
            'total'     => $json['total'],
        ];
        unset(
            $json['links'],
            $json['path'],
            $json['prev_page_url'],
            $json['first_page_url'],
            $json['last_page_url'],
            $json['next_page_url'],
            $json['current_page'],
            $json['from'],
            $json['to'],
            $json['last_page'],
            $json['per_page'],
            $json['total'],
        );
        return $json;
    });
}
```

Now you can just use it like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return App\Models\User::jsonPaginate();
});
```

PS.:

- The DocBlock is to bypass the Intelephense error when grabbing `$this` from an anonymous function / callback.
- I've used in my example two customizations, one is to "move" some keys into a `meta` key, the other one is to remove the unwanted ones, you can customize it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `ResourceCollection` overrides your custom response structure and adds some extra properties [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php#L112-L114). You can fix this (broken IMO) behavior by overriding the `toResponse()` method like so:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return JsonResource::toResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this question while trying to do the same. With Laravel 8, it seems you can do this, but you can't use the resource collection. You simply use the resource class you created. So, in your case, instead of using `EntityCollection`, you use `EntityResource`

Sample below:

```
$results = EntityResource::collection(Entity::paginate($pageSize));

return response()->json([
    'data' => $results,
    'lastPage' => $results->lastPage()
]);
```

With this approach, you essentially build the metadata yourself. You can reference Laravel's pagination documentation to see what other methods are available for building out your own metadata.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Answer (score 0):

###### That solution works for me

I had called `paginate()` within the query form `repository` class. I got a paginated response. So, I need to handle pagination on the `query level` not in the `resource response` layer. i.e.

```
User::where('user_type', 'attendee')->paginate()
```

###### Resouce calling example:

```
$attendees = $this->userRepository->getAttendees($filters);
$attendees = (AttendeeResource::collection($attendees))->response()->getData(true);
```

When we call a resource with the above syntax then it calls `AnonymousResourceCollection` class behind the scene. so, to override the pagination data globally instead of repeating same thing in multiple `Resources` or overriding `Resource` classes. I created a `macro` in `AppServiceProvider` **boot** method and introduced my format for pagination.

###### Macro Snippet:

```
AnonymousResourceCollection::macro('paginationInformation', function ($request, $paginated, $default) {
    unset($default['links'], $default['meta']['links']);
    return $default;
});
```

###### Resource Class Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AttendeeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
        self::wrap("users");
    }

    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```